# Disable lazy-loading for List of String in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I'm trying to avoid hibernate's lazy-loading mechanism and I've created this list object with the Eager FetchType, which I would suppose would do it:

```
@JsonIgnore
@CollectionTable(name = "nav", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="conn"))
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@IndexColumn(name="filter") private List<String> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
```

But I'm still reading a PersistentList, instead of java.util.List. Any idea on what may be wrong ?

I'm not using xml configurations.

Comment: i think you should remove @CollectionTable(name = "nav", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="conn"))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To avoid lazy loading you have to set `lazy = true` and instead of `FetchType.EAGER` make it `FetchType.JOIN`.

for annotations based mapping refer to the below link:
[http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching]

let me know if it helps you.

Comment: lazy=true? r u using xml based mapping or annotation based?

Comment: Annotation based, so I can't use that, I think.

Comment: yes in annotation you have fetch = FetchType.LAZY or fetch = FetchType.EAGER. We don't have lazy=true

Comment: refer to the below link:   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching

Comment: I think you should read it again... In the document lazy=true is never used. only FetchType.LAZY or FetchType.EAGER has been used through out the document.

Comment: yes i read it and for the annotations i have provided link please see it

Comment: Using the annotations @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE) @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) instead of the @ElementCollection and using ArrayList<> instead of List<>, as pointed by Edmondo1984. Thanks.

Comment: PersistentList is not a Lazy collection in Hibernate. A lazy collection is a CGLIB proxy which retrieves the data from the database when accessed, while PersistentList is Hibernate own implementation of java.util.List. I was not aware you could directly persist an ArrayList, I am actually almost sure that you would not be able to persist a OneToMany relationship as an array list.

Comment: Then this isn't a question on persistency, only on how to avoid the retrieving of "persisting-Hibernate" objects. As it is, it did what I wanted. (I still haven't checked out the behaviour on loading maps.)

Answer (score 0):

A Persistent List is a non-lazy collection that Hibernate uses to correctly store and retrieve data from the databases. It is not a case that when you define your persistable entities you cannot use Java collection implementations, such as ArrayList or LinkedList, but only interfaces. In fact, you are asking for a List and you are getting PersistentList, which totally respect the contract of the interface.

If you remove the eagerness and debug your class, you will see a lazy collection appearing, and this is typically a CGLIB proxy.